# I cannot multiply the arrays correctly in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

Here is my code - all it does for the `weightedProduct()` is return `0.00`.

Where did I go wrong? I need it to multiply the `units * price` and return the `product`.

```
public class FrameArray {

    private String frameInventory;
    private int[] units;
    private double[] price;
    private double product;

    public FrameArray( String frame, int[] unitsArray, double[] priceArray, double product )
    {
        frameInventory = frame;
        units = unitsArray;
        price = priceArray;
        product = weightedProduct(unitsArray, priceArray);
    }

    public void setFrameInventory( String frame )
    {
        frameInventory = frame;
    }

    public String getFrameInventory()
    {
        return frameInventory;
    }
     public double weightedProduct(int[] unitsArray, double[] priceArray){
            double value = 0;
            double product = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < unitsArray.length; i++){
                value = (double) (unitsArray[i] * priceArray[i]);
                product = product + value;}
            return product;
     }    

    public void displayMessage()
    {   
        System.out.printf( "Current frame inventory\n\n");
    }

    public void processInventory()
    {
        outputInventory();
    }

    public void outputInventory()
    {
        System.out.println( "Inventory levels:\n");
        System.out.printf( "Style     Qty    Price     Value\n\n");

        for (int frame = 0; frame < price.length; frame++) 
            System.out.printf( "Frame %2d: %3d    %5.2f    %5.2f\n", 
                    frame + 1, units[ frame ], price[ frame], product );    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing in a `product` on the constructor? Assigning a value to it does nothing. It will *not* be returned to caller, because Java is pass-by-value, not pass-by-ref.

Comment: Noticed the `product` field, but the `product =` in the constructor assigns to the `product` *parameter*, not the field. Drop the parameter and/or qualify with `this.`, preferably both.

Comment: I don't understand - do I take product out of the weightedProduct()?

Comment: You remove the `product` parameter from the constructor, and you change `weightedProduct` to `private static`, and you qualify all field references with `this.`, e.g. `this.units = unitsArray`.

Comment: Thank you for your help - it works better than it did. Now it adds all the multiplied totals together. But, better than 0.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is effect of **Shadowing**.

I think there is ambiguity in the `FrameArray()`.

The `product` used in the statement just assigns the value to the parameter in function scope.

```
product = weightedProduct(unitsArray, priceArray);
```

Just correct it as shown:

```
public FrameArray( String frame, int[] unitsArray, double[] priceArray, double product )
{
    frameInventory = frame;
    units = unitsArray;
    price = priceArray;
    this.product = weightedProduct(unitsArray, priceArray);
}
```

You can simply **remove** the `product` parameter for the `FrameArray()` too as it is just updating that state variable through `weightedProduct()` function`s return value.